# Irreducibility of degree $6$ representation of $GL(3,2)$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

The group $GL(3,2)$ acts on the Fano plane $P^2(\mathbb{F}_2)$, which consists of projective lines in $3$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. This action is transitive, as well as doubly-transitive. Then using problem $2.6(c)$ of section $2.4$ of J. P. Serre's book "Finite representations of group", we can prove that this will decompose as a $1$ dimensional and a $6$ dimensional representation of the group.

Can this be directly proven, without using the character theory?

Taking the vector space which has basis elements as elements of $P^2\mathbb({F}_2)$, we see that sum of the vectors span an invariant subspace. Since $\mathbb{C}GL(3,2)$ is semisimple, this subspace has a complement of dimension $6$.

If we denote $P^2(\mathbb{F}_2)=\{e_i:1\leq i\leq 7\}$, then complement of the invariant space is generated by $\{e_i-e_{i+1}:1\leq i\leq 6\}$. Can we somehow prove that this space does not have any invariant subspace?

Comment: This is true for the permutation rep of any 2-transitive action. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471279/doubly-transitive-group-has-irreducible-augmentation-module-follow-up) for a character-free proof.