# Representation space for the Alternating groups $A_n$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Is there a systematic way to construct the representation spaces for an irreducible representation $\phi:A_n\rightarrow {GL}(V)$, where $V$ is called as representation space. For example doubly transitive actions give rise to an irreducible representation spaces. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471279/doubly-transitive-group-has-irreducible-augmentation-module-follow-up). But not all can be constructed this way.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, the alternating group $A_7$ has an irreducible representation of degree $15$. But how do I find the corresponding representation space? This can not be constructed by doubly transitive actions on $16$ points, since $A_7$  doesn't have any transitive action on $16$ points, which can be found [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/T31.html#30t88).

I would like to get some reference for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is to ask GAP:

```
gap> LoadPackage("repsn");;
gap> grp := AlternatingGroup(7);
Alt( [ 1 .. 7 ] )
gap> chi := First(Irr(grp), chi -> Degree(chi)=15);
Character( CharacterTable( Alt( [ 1 .. 7 ] ) ), [ 15, -1, 3, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1 ] )
gap> rep := IrreducibleAffordingRepresentation(chi);;
```

If you want to know the matrix for a particular permutation, you use:

```
gap> Image(rep, (1,2)(3,4));
[ [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1 ],
  [ -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -2 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -2 ] ]
```

A similar technique to permutation representations is induced representations, but this representation is not induced (the only subgroups of index dividing 15 are the PGL(3,2)s, and they are index 15 but with no nontrivial linear characters).

You could restrict a representation of the symmetric group on 7 points. The [Specht module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht_module) with partition [3,1,1,1,1] or [5,1,1] will work. This works for many of the irreducible representations of alternating groups. If you like that technique, then [Sagan's book on the representations of **The Symmetric Group**](https://www.google.com/search?q=bruce+sagan+symmetric+group) is a popular choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..